# How does the Mind Gem in the Chitauri Scepter brainwash people into loyalty and obedience?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

When I was watching the first Avengers movie, Loki brainwashed people into absolute loyalty and total obedience by touching their chest with the Mind Gem Chitauri Scepter. Does it have to be the chest area? Would any part of the body do, like the forehead?

Also, does the person to be loyal to have to be in visual sight of the brainwashed person, or be the one holding the staff? In Age of Ultron, using the same stuff, one of Ultron's drones brainwashed the Korean scientist, not Ultron himself, yet the Korean scientist followed Ultron's instructions. I think Ultron was not in visual sight either.

Comment: It does have to be the chest, as Stark was immune due to his chest reactor.

Comment: Thanks; what if Loki had touched Stark on the forehead? I was wondering why the chest? I mean, I know the Marvel Cinematic Universe is purely fictional and imaginary but isn't the brain containing a person's mind located at the top of the head?

Comment: If he could he probably would. I don't know why it has to be the chest, though.

Comment: @RogueJedi We don't know that it has to be the *chest*. It just may need to make more direct contact/touch the skin (the blade would poke through a shirt, like Hawkeye's or Tony's like a needle), but on Tony just met the reactor instead.

Comment: @creationedge Loki tries to poke Tony in the chest several times, implying that it has to be the chest.

Comment: Good point, but I wish there has been more chance to explore this in the marvel movies.

Comment: @RogueJedi - He might have kept trying because it had to be the chest, or because he didn't know why it hadn't worked.  If CreationEdge  was right, it might be as simple as torso=larger target or less likely to accidentally maim new minions if the aim is a bit off.  And without knowing the reactor was why it didn't work, instead of some immunity it might not have occurred to him that moving the poke would help.  Actually, if it is related to the heart, rather than the mind?  I wonder if it would have worked poking the back as well (for Stark or anyone).

Answer (score 1):

This is the picture of the gems that power *The Infinity Gauntlet*:

[image]

The gem in the scepter is considered as *The Mind Gem*. It does make sense that they use it on the head area instead of chest area.

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, the Korean scientest follows Ultron's orders even without the visual confirmation of Ultron's existense beside her.

> **Because The Mind Gem is the source of Ultron's sentience.**

In the movie, Tony Stark uses Loki's Scepter to create artificial intelligence peacekeeping program (ULTRON), it backfires pretty bad but that's irrelevant. This might be the proof why the scientist follows Ultron's orders.

*Mind Gem allows the user to greatly strengthen and enhance mental and psionic power and access the thoughts and dreams of other beings. Backed by the Power Gem, the Mind Gem can access all minds in existence simultaneously. When searching for it, the Grandmaster apparently discovered that the Mind Gem was the manifestation of the universal subconscious.*

In the series *Warlock and The Infinity Watch*, the Gems are distributed by Adam Warlock to a group he dubs "the Infinity Watch", with himself as the leader and once again guardian of his old companion, the Soul Gem. He names the astral samurai Gamora guardian of the Time Gem, the hedonistic rogue Pip the Troll guardian of the Space Gem, the impervious powerhouse Drax the Destroyer guardian of the Power Gem, the Eternal-trained human mystic telepath Moondragon guardian of the Mind Gem, and an unknown member (later revealed to be Thanos himself) guardian of the Reality Gem.

**Bonus Information:** Some die-hard Marvel fans does not accept the stone in Loki's Scepter as The Mind Gem because they think Thanos would never give up such strong weapon (for more info please check The Infinity Gauntlet). They think the stone as something that is powered by Tesseract. But in *Guardians of the Galaxy*, Ronan the Accuser has *The Power Gem*.

Comment: The first Avengers movie suggested that the Chitauri Scepter was powered by the Tesseract, and prior to Age of Ultron there was a case to be made that it was just that. But Age of Ultron has indisputably settled the matter. I don't think anyone still argues that the Scepter is not powered by the Mind Stone. (BTW, they are called stones in the films.)